# pandas DataFrame drops index when passing to kdb+ (using qPython API)

Tags: python, pandas, kdb, q-lang, exxeleron-q

I am trying to pass time-series data from `Python` to `q/kdb+`.

One solution out there is [`qPython` module](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython), offering seamless conversion from `q` table/dictionary to Pandas.

The problem is when trying to pass **from** Pandas to `q`, the time index in `DataFrame` (in the column `Date`) doesn't quite make it to the `q` side. Reproducible code:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
import numpy
import qpython.qconnection as qconnection # requires installation of qPython module from https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6)
f=web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end) # download Ford stock data (ticker "F") from Yahoo Finance web service
f.ix[:5]  # explore first 5 rows of the DataFrame
# Out:
#             Open  High  Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
#    Date
# 2010-01-04 10.17 10.28 10.05 10.28  60855800       9.43 
# 2010-01-05 10.45 11.24 10.40 10.96 215620200      10.05
# 2010-01-06 11.21 11.46 11.13 11.37 200070600      10.43
# 2010-01-07 11.46 11.69 11.32 11.66 130201700      10.69
# 2010-01-08 11.67 11.74 11.46 11.69 130463000      10.72

q = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, pandas = True) # define connection interface parameters. Assumes we have previously started q server on port 5000 with `q.exe -p 5000` command
q.open() # open connection
q('set', numpy.string_('yahoo'), f) # pass DataFrame to q table named `yahoo`
q('5#yahoo') # display top 5 rows from newly created table on q server 
# Out:
#    Open  High  Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
# 0 10.17 10.28 10.05 10.28  60855800       9.43 
# 1 10.45 11.24 10.40 10.96 215620200      10.05
# 2 11.21 11.46 11.13 11.37 200070600      10.43
# 3 11.46 11.69 11.32 11.66 130201700      10.69
# 4 11.67 11.74 11.46 11.69 130463000      10.72
```

As you can see, the q table doesn't have the `Date` column that was present in `f` DataFrame as index.

How to efficiently (for large data) pass the datetime index to q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While serializing `DataFrame` objects the `qPython` checks for the presence of `meta` attribute. If the attribute is not present, `DataFrame` is serialized as q table and index columns are *skipped* in the process. If you want to *preserve* the index columns, you have to set the `meta` attribute and provide type hinting to enforce representation a q keyed table.

Please take a look at the modified sample:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
import numpy
import qpython.qconnection as qconnection # requires installation of qPython module from https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython

from qpython import MetaData
from qpython.qtype import QKEYED_TABLE


start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6)
f=web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end) # download Ford stock data (ticker "F") from Yahoo Finance web service
f.ix[:5]  # explore first 5 rows of the DataFrame
# Out:
#             Open  High  Low  Close    Volume  Adj Close
#    Date
# 2010-01-04 10.17 10.28 10.05 10.28  60855800       9.43 
# 2010-01-05 10.45 11.24 10.40 10.96 215620200      10.05
# 2010-01-06 11.21 11.46 11.13 11.37 200070600      10.43
# 2010-01-07 11.46 11.69 11.32 11.66 130201700      10.69
# 2010-01-08 11.67 11.74 11.46 11.69 130463000      10.72

q = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, pandas = True) # define connection interface parameters. Assumes we have previously started q server on port 5000 with `q.exe -p 5000` command
q.open() # open connection
f.meta = MetaData(**{'qtype': QKEYED_TABLE}) # enforce to serialize DataFrame as keyed table
q('set', numpy.string_('yahoo'), f) # pass DataFrame to q table named `yahoo`
q('5#yahoo') # display top 5 rows from newly created table on q server 
# Out:
#              Open   High    Low  Close     Volume  Adj Close
# Date                                                         
# 2010-01-04  10.17  10.28  10.05  10.28   60855800       9.43
# 2010-01-05  10.45  11.24  10.40  10.96  215620200      10.05
# 2010-01-06  11.21  11.46  11.13  11.37  200070600      10.43
# 2010-01-07  11.46  11.69  11.32  11.66  130201700      10.69
# 2010-01-08  11.67  11.74  11.46  11.69  130463000      10.72
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying one of the other APIs?
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/python-api
I would also report the issue on their github page.