# Passing pandas DataFrame containing string column to kdb+ (using qPython API)

Tags: python, pandas, kdb, q-lang, exxeleron-q

[`exxeleron/qPython`](https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython) module allows to send the pandas `DataFrame` to `kdb+/q`'s table.

Let's prepare the data:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
import numpy

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6)
f = web.DataReader(["F","MSFT"], 'yahoo', start, end) # download stock data from Yahoo Finance
f = f.to_frame().reset_index() # flatten the MultiIndex to have a sym column, see below
f = f[["Date","minor","Close"]]
f.columns = ["dt","sym","val"] # just give comfortable names
```

The `DataFrame` object to be passed then looks like:

```
f.head()
# Out: 
#           dt   sym    val
# 0 2010-01-04     F  10.28
# 1 2010-01-04  MSFT  30.95
# 2 2010-01-05     F  10.96
# 3 2010-01-05  MSFT  30.96
# 4 2010-01-06     F  11.37

f.dtypes
# Out: 
# dt     datetime64[ns]
# sym            object
# val           float64
```

When I try to send it to `kdb+/q`, I get the following error:

```
import qpython.qconnection as qconnection
q = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, pandas = True)
q.open()
q('set', numpy.string_('tbl'), f)

# File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qpython\_pandas.py", line 159, in _write_pandas_series
#   data = data.fillna(QNULLMAP[-abs(qtype)][1])
# KeyError: -10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sym` column in the `DataFrame` is ambiguous for the `qpython` and it cannot determinate the default serialization properly. In such case, you have to provide type hinting for columns conversion, by setting the `meta` attribute:

```
from qpython import MetaData 
from qpython.qtype import QSYMBOL_LIST

f.meta = MetaData(sym = QSYMBOL_LIST)
q('set', numpy.string_('tbl'), f)
```

This instructs `qpython` to serialize `sym` column as q symbol list:

```
q)meta tbl                              
c  | t f a                              
---| -----                              
dt | p                                  
sym| s                                  
val| f 

q)tbl                                   
dt                            sym  val  
----------------------------------------
2010.01.04D00:00:00.000000000 F    10.28
2010.01.04D00:00:00.000000000 MSFT 30.95
2010.01.05D00:00:00.000000000 F    10.96
..
```

Alternatively, you can represent `sym` column as a q generic list containing strings. You can also apply type conversion to other columns:

```
from qpython import MetaData 
from qpython.qtype import QSTRING_LIST, QINT_LIST, QDATETIME_LIST

f.meta = MetaData(sym = QSTRING_LIST, val = QINT_LIST, dt = QDATETIME_LIST)
q('set', numpy.string_('tbl'), f)
```

which results in:

```
q)meta tbl                          
c  | t f a                          
---| -----                          
dt | z                              
sym|                                
val| i  

q)tbl                               
dt                      sym    val  
----------------------------------  
2010.01.04T00:00:00.000 "F"    10   
2010.01.04T00:00:00.000 "MSFT" 30   
..
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, works like a charm. I also had to add `from qpython import MetaData` `from qpython.qtype import QSYMBOL_LIST` as per your previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385137/pandas-dataframe-drops-index-when-passing-to-kdb-using-qpython-api

Comment: I've added missing imports to the snippet - thanks for spotting.
In addition, I extended the docs with a type hinting information:
http://qpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pandas.html#type-hinting